# Is there a correct way to use the idiom " from then on " + future ? Example : From then on, they'll be friends for life

Tags: idiom-request

Meaning: " From a particular day / event ( **still to come** ), they'll be(come) friends for life. " I've read here that the idiom " from then on " is only used to describe an event already happened, from the past. If so, what can I say to replace " from then on " in the sense of my example ? " *These two boys do not stop arguing. In my opinion, they would need a good little fight. From then on ( Google suggests from there ), they will be the best friends in the world.* An idiom / expression in 3 syllables needed, just like "from then on".

Answer (score 0):

Three syllables? "*After that* they'll be friends for life."

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jack, but " after that " does not sound good enough to my ears, it does not really fit my wishes in the context of song lyrics. Moreover, I've read somewhere that : ( I quote ) " " “from then on” could basically be used with any tense. The word “then” refers to a specific point in time and that point in time could be either in the past,( the present ) or in the future – it depends on the context. ". The reason why I don't know what to think anymore ...

Answer (score 0):

A three syllables phrase you might be looking for  is *"Happily ever after"* as in:

> They lived *happily ever after*

Answer (score 0):

**From then on** is not an idiom as it has its literal meaning (= from that time onwards).

That said,

"These two boys are always arguing. In my opinion, they need a good little fight. From then on, they will be the best of friends."

You have used the phrase correctly.

> " I've read here that the idiom " from then on " is only used to describe an event already happened, from the past.

If you read what you have written, they will be friends after they have fought: thus the fighting is in the past. The "then" refers to the time the fight ends and guidance is still good.